# How to setup authentication code for Java web RESTful service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authentication, cryptography

I'm reaching out for some help drawing out a solution and I want to make sure I'm doing it securely and properly.

I'm using the following as a resource, as well: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

**The Task**

1. Generate a token (aka authentication code)
2. Embed token in JSP and send token via URL GET/POST to a PHP server.*
3. PHP server makes a RESTful Web Service call to JSP server. The call passes the token.
4. JSP server receives token and uses it to authenticate the user and then returns requested data to PHP server. This is a continuation of the same RESTful Web Service.

You can see here that the JSP server will generate and decode the token. The question is how do I securely generate this token (aka authentication code)?

Do I need to use some kind of private key?

Or, can I apply a salt that includes, amongst other things, date and time, then store the salt and token in a database?

Thank you very much for any help.

**UPDATE**

*I want to flesh this part out to make it more clear what's happening. The user is logged into a JSP web application. One of the JSP pages introduces the PHP web application to the user. On this same JSP page, there is a link which opens up a PHP page that's located on a separate domain, a separate server (obviously, it's the PHP server). This PHP page is an HTTPS login page for the PHP web application. However, instead of entering a user name and password, the idea is to use a token to authenticate.

I have direct control of the JSP server, but I don't have direct control over the PHP server. Someone else controls it, but I can negotiate the handshake process with this person.

With all the above said, how can I securely pass the token from JSP to the PHP login page, since GET/POST apparently is not secure?

Comment: Putting a token into an URL is not secure. e.g. An URL is usually logged with including all query parameters, remains in a browser history, etc. Use Authorization header and look on HMAC or OAuth2.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate on this authorization header, perhaps with an example or some good resources I can study? Would this auth header be employed in the RESTful service or when sending the token from JSP to PHP? I'll update the question to clarify the JSP to PHP part.